# Scala not perfoming an exact match

Tags: regex, scala

I'm relatively new to Scala, I'm trying to do some basic Regex pattern matching:

In the example below I'm trying to match a string that gets sent to an Akka TCP actor:

```
class ConnectionHandler extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import Tcp._

  def receive = {
    case Received(data) => {
      log.info("Data received! " +  data)
      log.info("Date received! " + data.decodeString("UTF-8"))

      val pattern = """(?ms)(<START>>)(((.+?)=(.+?));)+(END)""".r

      val decoded = data.decodeString("UTF-8").trim

      decoded match {
        case pattern()      => log.info("OK")
        case pattern(t)     => log.info("A bit")
        case _              => log.info("NOK :(")
      }

      pattern findFirstIn decoded match {
        case Some(v) => log.info("Found: " + v); true
        case None => log.info("Not found") ; false
      }
    }

    case PeerClosed => {
      log.info("Peer closed!")
      context stop self
    }

    case _              => log.info("Received unknown message")
  }
}
```

Below is an example string that I'm receiving:

```
<START>>=ITM_NT_Logical_Disk;source='ITM';sub_source='Primary:PX810001999:NT';cms_hostname='pc120003350';cms_port='3661';integration_type='N';master_reset_flag='';appl_label='';situation_name='Y_WINDOWS_TEST';situation_type='S;Total_Size=152617~';END
```

As far as I an see, my Regex should work, though admittedly I'm not very good at them.

The strange thing is that the result for this part

```
decoded match {
    case pattern()      => log.info("OK")
    case pattern(t)     => log.info("A bit")
    case _              => log.info("NOK :(")
  }
```

is NOK, but the result for this part:

```
pattern findFirstIn decoded match {
    case Some(v) => log.info("Found: " + v); true
    case None => log.info("Not found") ; false
}
```

is that it not only finds a value, but it matches the entire exact string. (Value of 'v' is exactly that of the string sent over the wire, or that of 'decoded')

At first I thought the newline appended at the end of the string would cause the problem, but I added

```
val decoded = data.decodeString("UTF-8").trim
```

but no luck :(

I also tried simplifying the Regex to

```
val pattern = """(?ms)(<START>>).*?(END)""".r
```

but that doesn't seem to improve my results.

I want to make sure that the string ends exactly with "END", because I need to perform some manipulation afterwards, so `findFirstIn` is not preferable.

For the record, I've tried validating my Regex with a multitude of helper tools, but they all seem to indicate that I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

That produces 6 match captures as shows by [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tL3eN6/1) and therefore you can change your pattern matching as follows:

```
decoded match {
  case pattern(_, _, _, _, _, _) => log.info("OK")
  case _ => log.info("NOK :(")
}
```

Comment: So I need to specify the EXACT amount of pattern matches? So if I were to have 7 pattern matches, it will fail UNLESS I do case pattern(_, _, _, _, _, _, _) => log.info("OK")?

Comment: Is there a way to specify 'case ONE OR MORE' pattern match?

Comment: Remove the capture parentheses from the regular expression then you can use just pattern without any underscores.

Comment: Alternatively, you can capture them all using `@ _*` to get all the matches in a list: `case pattern(matches @ _*) => log.info(matches.toString)`